# Regex (with lookahead/lookbehind extensions) that that maches on anything in node_modules besides a certain sub folder

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

For a Jest config file where I am configuring code transformations, I am trying to create a pattern that will ignore all files in `node_modules/.pnpm`, except a certain package (a fork of `@react-unicons`), but I am consistently failing with the whole lookahead attempts, either matching too much or too little.

Is this even possible?

From the list of strings below, I only want to filter out all other lines from `.pnpm` other than the folder `github.com+ACME+react-unicons@763e2d31e16c2abba8924f5d5970452912f18704`. That means files from outside of `node_modules/.pnpm` needs to be kept in the output.

```
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github.com+ACME+react-unicons@763e2d31e16c2abba8924f5d5970452912f18704/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons/icons/uil-times.js",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github.com+ACME+react-unicons@763e2d31e16c2abba8924f5d5970452912f18704/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons/icons/uil-arrow-left.js",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github.com+ACME+react-unicons@763e2d31e16c2abba8924f5d5970452912f18704/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons/.github/workflows/autotag.yml",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github.com+ACME+react-unicons@763e2d31e16c2abba8924f5d5970452912f18704/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons/icons/uil-transaction.js",
/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/exif-js",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/eslint-plugin-testing-library",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/@typescript-eslint",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/chart.js",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/@iconscout",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/react-redux",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.bin",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/stmux",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/only-allow",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/react-addons-deep-compare",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/code/my-app/src/components/one-offs",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/code/my-app/src/components/one-offs/MainGuiLayout.tsx",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/code/my-app/src/components/one-offs/AppWrapper.jsx"
```

```js
const files = [
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+runtime@7.17.2/node_modules/@babel/runtime/regenerator/index.js",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/regenerator-runtime@0.13.9/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/lodash@4.17.21/node_modules/lodash/isEmpty.js",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/@material-ui+core@4.12.3_b8fdba992ce7d797017dc07106486496/node_modules/@material-ui/core/Zoom/Zoom.js",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github.com+ACME+react-unicons@763e2d31e16c2abba8924f5d5970452912f18704/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons/icons/uil-times.js",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github.com+ACME+react-unicons@763e2d31e16c2abba8924f5d5970452912f18704/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons/icons/uil-arrow-left.js",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github.com+ACME+react-unicons@763e2d31e16c2abba8924f5d5970452912f18704/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons/.github/workflows/autotag.yml",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github.com+ACME+react-unicons@763e2d31e16c2abba8924f5d5970452912f18704/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons/icons/uil-transaction.js",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github-slugger@1.4.0",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github-slugger@1.4.0/node_modules",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github-slugger@1.4.0/node_modules/github-slugger",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/exif-js",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/eslint-plugin-testing-library",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/@typescript-eslint",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/chart.js",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/@iconscout",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/react-redux",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.bin",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/stmux",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/only-allow",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/react-addons-deep-compare",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/code/my-app/src/components/one-offs",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/code/my-app/src/components/one-offs/MainGuiLayout.tsx",
"/home/me/code/proj-foo/code/my-app/src/components/one-offs/AppWrapper.jsx"
]

const nodeModulesPattern = 'node_modules'
const nodeModulesPattern0 = 'node_modules/.pnpm'
const nodeModulesPattern1 = 'node_modules/(?!@iconscout)'
const nodeModulesPattern2 = 'node_modules/(?!\.pnpm)'
const nodeModulesPattern3 = 'node_modules/.pnpm/(?!(github.com\+ACME))/'

const re = new RegExp(nodeModulesPattern0)

// only print what does NOT match
for ( const line of files ) {
  if(!re.test(line)) console.log("NO match: ", line); 
}
```

A correct regex would mean the output wuold contain lines starting with "NO match: " for all of the following files (which is a subset of the `files` array above):

```
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github.com+ACME+react-unicons@763e2d31e16c2abba8924f5d5970452912f18704/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons/icons/uil-times.js",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github.com+ACME+react-unicons@763e2d31e16c2abba8924f5d5970452912f18704/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons/icons/uil-arrow-left.js",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github.com+ACME+react-unicons@763e2d31e16c2abba8924f5d5970452912f18704/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons/.github/workflows/autotag.yml",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.pnpm/github.com+ACME+react-unicons@763e2d31e16c2abba8924f5d5970452912f18704/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons/icons/uil-transaction.js",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/exif-js",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/eslint-plugin-testing-library",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/@typescript-eslint",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/chart.js",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/@iconscout",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/@iconscout/react-unicons",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/react-redux",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/.bin",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/stmux",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/only-allow",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/node_modules/react-addons-deep-compare",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/code/my-app/src/components/one-offs",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/code/my-app/src/components/one-offs/MainGuiLayout.tsx",
    "/home/me/code/proj-foo/code/my-app/src/components/one-offs/AppWrapper.jsx"
```

Comment: What part do you want to match/extract? `^.*ACME\+react-unicon.*$` will match only the lines that you want?

Comment: Thanks for the interest :) As stated, "I only want to filter out all lines from .pnpm other than the folder github.com+ACME+react-unicons@". In case that was unclear/ambiguous, I have added an example output below. So basically, remove everything in `node_modules/.pnpm` apart from the react-unicorns folder in `node_modules/.pnpm/github.com+ACME+react-unicons/....`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion : we either accept

- the lines not containing pnpn in the first 7 group / + name
- the lines containing the string `github\.com\+ACME\+react-unicons`

```
^(((?!pnpm).)*|.*github\.com\+ACME\+react-unicons.*)$
```

Comment: The files listed was just a redacted example of what `node_modules` and the source folder could contain. There are tens of thousands more in any given order. There is no guarantee about where the `unicorns` package would appear. Also, the hash value of `763e2d31e16c2abba8924f5d5970452912f18704` would change any time I upgraded or anything like that, so relying on that would be very brittle.

Comment: I've modified to use the folder names and not the hash number.